# CSS :before/:after selectors are suddenly being positioned separately of parent div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I switched to a new computer, and all of a sudden the CSS `:after` and `:before` selectors no longer work.

**What's truly bizarre is that the `:before/:after` selectors I added before, on my other computer, display completely normally on my new computer. But any new ones I add now simply don't show up, even if I copy-and-paste the old code onto a new div.**

For example, this one:

**html**

```
<div id="wtf"></div>
```

**css**

```
#wtf {
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
}
#wtf:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: blue;
}
```

This code works when copied and pasted directly into a fiddle: ( http://jsfiddle.net/rLnrtu0x/ ) but only the red box displays on my local browser. No matter what I do, the blue box won't show. All other CSS behaves normally.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Tested on Mozilla 35.0.1 and Chrome 42.0.2311.152 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04. I can't retest it on my old computer because it broke, but I never had problems with `:before/:after` selectors before.

### **UPDATE**

I just found the selectors with my inspector. They actually display normally, but they are being positioned relative to `html`, not their parent div. Here again, with the code that I added before the computer change, the `:before/:after` selectors are positioned relative to the parent div. But the new code, even though it's copy-and-pasted, positions the selectors relative to the `html`. Why would this be?

Comment: You might be doing something wrong. Because this is unlikely to happen to you only.

Comment: What version of "Mozilla"?

Comment: You need to do what is called "troubleshooting". That means to systematically develop hypotheses about the possible problem, and test them one by one. For instance, in this case, copy the edited file back to the previous computer and see if it works. Try different browsers and versions on the two machines. View the console. Run a CSS linter.

Comment: @Mr_Green That's the question. But I don't see what I could possibly be doing wrong, because the code from the fiddle is literally copy and pasted.

Comment: @misterManSam I added mozilla and chrome versions above.

Comment: @torazaburo My previous computer broke, so I can't retest it on that. I tried it on chrome and the same problem is manifested. The web console displays no errors.

Comment: Continue troubleshooting. Open devtools, select the `#wtf` element, and view styles to see if the `:after` rule is present and being applied.

Comment: @torazaburo I actually found the selectors with my inspector. They are displaying normally, but they are now positioned relative to the html, where before they were positioned relative to the parent div.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The parent container needs to have `position`

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned "at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block." (src: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position))

So, your `:after` pseudo-element is not contained by its parent because the parent isn't "positioned" or its position is set to `static`.

The only explanation is that there must have been something in your previous setup that was applying `position` to `#wtf`, which allowed its child to be positioned absolutely within it.

**You can "fix" the issue by applying position to `#wtf` like so:**

```css
#wtf {
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
#wtf:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wtf"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's unrelated to the computer change. The `:before/:after` selectors are in fact displaying, but they are being positioned relative to the html, not the parent div, because the parent divs are absolutely positioned.

Comment: If the parent `div` has `position: absolute` set, then the `:after` pseudo-element would be positioned relative to it. The problem appears to be that there is no position applied to the parent container. See my answer above.